# How to assign a certain style id div tag

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning! I faced the problem create a javascript, that would restore the link with added style of a particular container div id. An example of my code:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="changeDiv()" onmouseout="defaultDiv()">Сантехника и электрика</a>
```

After a html code I added

```
<script>
      function changeDiv(){
      document.getElementById("images_1").style.width="230px";
      document.getElementById("images_1").style.height="162px";
      document.getElementById("images_1").style.top="0px";
    }
</script>
```

And now my question is how to style a particular id at once? If I use another 5 blocks div

Comment: I need some more background on this, which DIV would you try to style when hovering above the anchor tag? Would the anchor be part of the div layer?

Comment: make jsfiddle or explain more... you want to write less code ?

Comment: btw you can setup style once and change the var like `var style=document.getElementById(id).style;style.width="230px";/*....*/`

Answer (score 2):

Attach a class to your divs and then use document.getElementsByClassName('class'). This will return an array of elements which you can adapt with a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use arguments

```
<script>
      function changeDiv(ids){
      document.getElementById(ids).style.width="230px";
      document.getElementById(ids).style.height="162px";
      document.getElementById(ids").style.top="0px";
    }
</script>
```

And use like

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="changeDiv('image_1')" onmouseout="defaultDiv('do yourself')">Сантехника и электрика</a>
```

EDIT:(Answer to your comment)

```
<script> function changeDiv(ids){ document.getElementById(ids).style.borderRadius="5px"; } </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, and one more question. Why at such a code does not work?

<script>
      function changeDiv(ids){
      document.getElementById(ids).style.border-radius="5px";
    }
</script>

Comment: Use borderRadius instead of border-radius

Comment: And instead of me writing my ids id?   
<script>
      function changeDiv(images_1){
      document.getElementById(images_1).style.width="230px";
      document.getElementById(images_1).style.height="162px";
      document.getElementById(images_1).style.top="0px";
    }
</script>