# Incorrect JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem for a particular div element and its id. I want to add hover link style, but how to do this? I do not quite understand. My example:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="changeDiv('image_1')" onmouseout="defaultDiv('image_1')">Home</a>
```

And the script processing the addition of style:

```
<script>
  function changeDiv('image_1'){
    document.getElementById('image_1').style.width="230px";
    document.getElementById('image_1').style.height="162px";
    document.getElementById('image_1').style.top="0px";
  }
</script>
```

Tell me why this code does not work for my id `image_1`?

Comment: Your argument for the `changeDiv()` function is a string literal, what's that about?

Comment: If you want to change only style on hover, then why not use `:hover` pseudo class in css?

Comment: How to make css event to hover on the text link to change style pictures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign a certain style id div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010572/how-to-assign-a-certain-style-id-div-tag)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you specify a string literal instead of variable as the parameter of the function, which will cause a syntax error.

Try modifying your function to something like this:

```
<script>
function changeDiv(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.width="230px";
  document.getElementById(id).style.height="162px";
  document.getElementById(id).style.top="0px";
}
</script>
```

Now you can pass any id you want to the function when calling it.

**Cache a reference to the element for performance:**

For performance, you can also cache the element in a variable, so you don't have to look it up in the DOM three times:

```
<script>
function changeDiv(id){
  var elm = document.getElementById(id);
  elm.style.width="230px";
  elm.style.height="162px";
  elm.style.top="0px";
}
</script>
```

**Modify multiple elements at the same time:**

To modify multiple elements at the same time, you can call the function multiple times with different parameters:

```
onmouseover="changeDiv('image_1'); changeDiv('image_2');"
```

Or you can alter the function to take an array of strings with the IDs of elements.

```
<script>
function changeDivs(ids){
  for(var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
     var elm = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
     elm.style.width="230px";
     elm.style.height="162px";
     elm.style.top="0px";
  }
}
</script>
```

You can then call it like so:

```
onmouseover="changeDivs(['image_1', 'image_2'])"
```

Comment: Do not quite understand, and I use this script to a specific identifier? If I have 6 of them

Comment: @user971474 In links for the other divs you'll give another id: `onmouseout="defaultDiv('image_2')"`

Comment: @user971474 I've updated the example with a description on how you can handle multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

in function attribute must be var not string and you must called this var
for example

```
function myfunc(d){ //d is varble
alert(d);
```

}

Comment: Please add a code example to your answer to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<a  href="#" >
    <div id='image_1' onmouseover="changeDiv('image_1')" onmouseout="defaultDiv('image_1')" style="width:100px; height:18px; border-style:ridge;">
    Home
    </div>
</a>
```

If you just want pointer when mouse over. 
** add DIV border `border-style:ridge` for test...
** Create ID for your Tag.

This JS Script

```
  function changeDiv(IDS){
      document.getElementById(IDS).style.width="230px";
      document.getElementById(IDS).style.height="162px";
      document.getElementById(IDS).style.top="0px";
  }
```